# Update a Field/Column based on Current and Previous Record Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I need assistance with updating a field/column "IsLatest" based on the comparison between the current and previous record. I'm using CTE's syntax and I'm able to get the current and previous record but I'm unable updated field/column "IsLatest" which I need based on the field/column "Value" of the current and previous record.

Example

Current Output

```
Dates                   Customer    Value   IsLatest
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000    1            12  1

Dates                   Customer    Value   IsLatest
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000    1            12  0
2010-01-02 00:00:00.000    1            30  1

Dates                   Customer    Value   IsLatest
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000    1            12  0
2010-01-02 00:00:00.000    1            30  0
2010-01-03 00:00:00.000    1            13  1
```

Expected Final Output

```
Dates                   Customer    Value   ValueSetId IsLatest
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000    1            12     12          0
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000    1            12     13          0
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000    1            12     14          0

2010-01-02 00:00:00.000    1            30     12          0
2010-01-02 00:00:00.000    1            30     13          0
2010-01-02 00:00:00.000    1            30     14          0

2010-01-03 00:00:00.000    1            13     12          0
2010-01-03 00:00:00.000    1            13     13          0
2010-01-03 00:00:00.000    1            13     14          0

2010-01-04 00:00:00.000    1            14     12          0
2010-01-04 00:00:00.000    1            14     13          0
2010-01-04 00:00:00.000    1            14     14          1
```

Comment: ;WITH    CustCTE
          AS (SELECT    Customer,
                        Value,
                        Dates,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer ORDER BY Dates) RowNum
              FROM      @Customers),

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH a AS
(
SELECT 
  Dates Customer Value, 
  row_number() over (partition by customer order by Dates desc, ValueSetId desc) rn
FROM @Customers)
SELECT Dates, Customer, Value, case when RN = 1 then 1 else 0 end IsLatest
FROM a
```

Comment: Hi t-clausen.dk, thank for this. I had similar code to the above, however, I did not use the DESC as my idea was to use the current and previous record, which got me into a twist.

Comment: Hi t-clausen.dk, just another question, how would I changed the code if above table has another field which uniquely identifies a row but the above output still needs to be the same. Example  foreach date, per customer you have 3 different values. The additional field "PeriodSetId" identifies the record for a point in time in hours E.g 12,15 14, etc.

Comment: @LindsayFisher not sure what you are asking, can you change your question with expected results and testdata to illustrate ?

Comment: Hi t-clausen.dk, I changed the expected results example above, however, I figured it out as well. I include ValueSetId in the "partition by" statement with the customer which brought me the incorrect results and after removing the ValueSetId field but including it in the "Order By" with a DESC it worked.See the code;WITH a AS
(
 SELECT 
 Dates, Customer, Value, ValueSetId, row_number() over (partition by customer order by Dates desc, ValueSetId DESC) rn
 FROM @Customers
)
SELECT Dates, Customer, Value, ValueSetId, case when RN = 1 then 1 else 0 end IsLatest
FROM a
ORDER BY Dates DESC, Customer

Comment: @LindsayFisher yes, that would do it in your example